# SQL - Select statements within case

Tags: sql, database, oracle, select, case

How do I achieve this using SQL case statement?

```
select count(*) x  from t_table where file_id = 310012; 

if x<>0 : select distinct status from t_table where file_id = 310012 
else : return x
```

Comment: you probably need this, <http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
See the code below:

SELECT CASE COUNT(*) 
                    WHEN COUNT(*) > 0 THEN 
                    (SELECT status FROM t_table  WHERE file_id = 310012) 
                    ELSE null END AS x 
FROM t_table  WHERE file_id = 310012;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do what you want with a `union all`:

```
select distinct status
from t_table
where file_id = 310012 
union all
select 0
from dual
where not exists (select 1 from t_table where tile_id = 320023);
```

However, returning a single row with `0` seems like a bad idea, because it could be confused with a value `status`.

Note:  You should use `'0'` if `status` is a string.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to count records. Just do only one query:

```
select distinct status from t_table where file_id = 310012
```

When the query return some rows, then x must be <> 0
If the query returns an empty resultset, then x must be equal to 0, and you get the second part of `if x <> 0 then ..... else return x`
As a bonus you get a higher processing speed, because you run only one query against the table, not two.